# How to get CSS selectors which contain specific colors?

Tags: java, php, jquery, css, stylesheet

First, sorry that I didn't put any code here, since I hadt no idea how to do it.

What I need is to get all the CSS selectors (within a CSS file) which specifically contain a color... let's say #3C3C3C, just for example.

**Example: Read a CSS file**

```
.first-selector div
{
color: #3C3C3C;
}
.second-selector span
{
background-color: #3C3C3C;
}
.thrid-selector
{
border: 1px solid #3C3C3C;
}
.fourth-selector .nothing
{
color: #00000;
}
```

**Expected Result - Extract it into array (only ones contains style with specific color)**

```
array[0]['selector'] == ".first-selector div"
array[0]['style'] == "color"

array[1]['selector'] == ".second-selector span"
array[1]['style'] == "background-color"

array[2]['selector'] == ".thrid-selector"
array[2]['style'] == "border"
```

What should be the logic to search for selectors which has specific color and put it into array?

**NOTE** This will be processed on server side.

Thanks

Comment: if you say "get", there is no PHP or Java involved.

Comment: and how is "java" related to web building?

Comment: WHen you say Java would you happen to mean jQuery?

Comment: Not at all, I just mention some languages I can use to extract it.

Comment: I am very interested at how Java could interact with HTML elements. Please tell me...

Comment: Ok I remove my language references.

The idea is 

- read css file.
- Search for selectors with specific color
- Put it all in array

That's what I am thinking of.

But the logic to search is my main problem lol

Comment: I expect an answer using all **Jquery**, **regex** and **css source doc**. And the solution will be too complicated for people to try solve.

Comment: @DanielCheung many developers use java for web building.

Comment: A better way is to step back and rethink the situation, flattening a mountain would be too complicated, why don't you dig a tunnel or walk around? What I want to say is, solving this answer is too wasted for such a small project. :(

Comment: @AtthaponJunpun-eak - your question is unclear. I understand that you want to parse a style sheet and return all selectors that contain a specific color. However, you do not state whether you want this done serverside (with PHP, Java, .Net etc) or clientside (JavaScript). Nor do you tell us how you want to interact with this data. Please can you clarify your requirements?

Comment: @Moob Oh~ I thought OP wanted to use Java in the client side, that's why...

Comment: @Moob Sorry for unclear, it must be done on server side.

Answer (score 0):

Using Files concepts, just write the logic in js to read the content of the file, then use some of the regular expressions logic or any other logic like splitting the content by passing the delimtre values. ACtually this is not the correct approach, just an idea

Comment: "an idea" won't be regarded as an answer. Actually, anyone can think of a solution, but you would have to realise it. ;)

Comment: Hmmm... yeah u r ryt. But with that approach we can get the output as expected. But I just mentioned as Idea because the person requested may or may not like the approach.  :(

Answer (score 0):

Javascript will let you access all the styles applied to the document. Check each one to see if it contains the color.

**CSS**

```
<style>
    .first-selector div
    {
        color: #3C3C3C;
    }
    .second-selector span
    {
        background-color: #3C3C3C;
    }
    .third-selector
    {
        border: 1px solid #3C3C3C;
    }
    .fourth-selector .nothing
    {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
    function getColorRules(color)
    {
//convert hex to rgb, since hex color styles are internally stored as rgb

        if (/[#]{0,1}[0-9A-F]{6}/.test(color))
        {
            color = color.replace('#', '');
            var r = parseInt(color.substr(0, 2), 16);
            var g = parseInt(color.substr(2, 2), 16);
            var b = parseInt(color.substr(4, 2), 16);
            color = "rgb(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")";
        }


        var returnArray = [];
        //grab all stylesheets
        var sheets = document.styleSheets;
        for (var i in sheets) {
            //to work in FF or chrome
            var rules = sheets[i].rules || sheets[i].cssRules;
            for (var r in rules)
            {
                //console.log(rules[r]);

                if (rules[r].cssText !== undefined) { //ignore empty or non css properties
                    if (rules[r].cssText.indexOf(color) > -1) //if the color is found in the style rule
                    { //add it to an array
                        var style = {
                            selector: rules[r].selectorText,
                            style: rules[r].style.cssText.split(":")[0]
                        };
                        returnArray.push(style);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return returnArray;
    }
    console.log(getColorRules("#3C3C3C"));
//[{ selector=".first-selector div", style="color"}, { selector=".second-selector span", style="background-color"}, { selector=".third-selector", style="border"}]
    console.log(getColorRules("red"));
// [{ selector=".fourth-selector .nothing", style="color"}]
</script>
```